# Who relations on database level work, that they are shown in workbench, phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, foreign-keys

I want to add a relation (one to many) to my MySql database.

*I have some table with blog posts and now I want to count the readers.*

I've written the migration, added models, controllers allright.

But If I am looking with workbench or phpMyAdmin I doesn't shown the relation in the designer and I don't know why - the relation is missing.

In the docu of Laravel I've found:

> Laravel also provides support for creating foreign key constraints, which are used to force referential integrity at the database level.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

I think my mistake is directly in my brain or in the migration file.

I imported some mysql dump in the past of the project.
There are relations which work - they are shown.

Questions I have:

- The relation on database level is undepented from the model?
- If I have an empty database relations are shown also, or need I import
  testdata?

I don't know where my error is.

What are the right steps to make an relation which is shown also visuell in workbench or phpMyAdmin on database level with laravel.

*If I migrate the whole project again no relations are visible.*

but php artisan migrate was successfull

Here some example of my migration files:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('column', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('count');
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');

        });
    }
```

Comment: I found some solution it was important to add $table->engine=“InnoDb”

Comment: You can have innodb as your default engine in MySQL so you can avoid specifying it inside the migration like this

Comment: What do you mean by "no relations are visible". How do you figured out that the references are not set?

Comment: The database was mixed with different storage engines, using InnoDb was the final solution to see relations in workbench.